# classic asp form handling

Tags: jquery, asp-classic

I have an "ancient" webpage that I need to instill some databasing capabalities into it, and I'm afraid I'm at a loss as I can't find a good enough resource on how to do that and how the queries goes as far as classic ASP.

so this is basically how it goes, I have a form validator which is written in jQuery, once the form is validated, I want to use a $.post request to send the data to a form processor (some sort of classic asp file).

I tried using Request.Form("field") but it isn't working.
I tried even using a $.get request using Request.QueryString("field") and I have no success there aswell.

some code:

```
Dim sConnection, objConn , objRS 
sConnection = "connection string" 
username = Request.QueryString("username")
sitename = Request.QueryString("site_name")
email = Request.QueryString("email")
comment = Request.QueryString("comment")
dataInsert = ("INSERT INTO larrydb_review (username, sitename, email, comment, rating) values (username, sitename, email, comment, rating)")
Set objConn = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
objConn.Open(sConnection) 

objConn.Execute dataInsert
```

I'm assuming that the SQL Query string isn't written correctly, but I afraid I haven't found where to write one properly using asp variables.

Any help will be greatly appreciated, 
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using the METHOD = POST in your form, to retrieve the data sent in your ASP page:

```
username = Request.form("username")
sitename = Request.form("site_name")
email = Request.form("email")
comment = Request.form("comment")
```

then to update the SQL Table you have to create a dynamic string as:

```
dataInsert = "INSERT INTO larrydb_review (username, sitename, email, comment, rating) values ('" & username & "', '" & sitename & "', '" & email & "', '" & comment & "', '" & rating & "')"
```

Also your variable sConnection = "connection string" must be properly fill with the connection string for your database like this example:

```
sConnection = "Provider=SQLNCLI.1;Password=YOUR_PASSWORD;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=YOU_USER_ID_FOR_DB;Initial Catalog=YOUR_DATABASE_NAME;Data Source=IP_YOUR_DB_SERVER;Use Regional Settings: Yes"
```

Comment: Make sure you sanitise your values before running them in a SQL query: otherwise someone can include SQL fragments in their form values and perform a good-old SQL injection attack.

Answer (score 0):

search Google Books. an example: http://books.google.com/books?id=LtdykpJvgXQC&pg=PA95&dq=asp+createobject.adodb.connection+insert.into&hl=en&ei=H0_rTbjqIMjiiAL_le3gCA&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=1&ved=0CC0Q6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false

build your INSERT string using the string concatenation operator "&":

`query = "INSERT INTO bleah (foo, bar) VALUES ('" & myfoo & "', '" & mybar & "')"`

books.google.com is a great resource for things like this. I haven't programmed classic ASP since the mid-90s.